# how can i use pointers with delete key word and the destructor?

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor

i was wondering how destructors can be made to work with pointers and delete.

i have a sprite pointer class i want it to call the destructor when the delete key word is used on it, however it is to my understanding this wont work as pointers don't leave memory until the end of a program.

Any advice on making these work together?

Comment: what do you mean, "leave memory"? pointers can be created/destroyed anytime WHILE a program is running.

Comment: You shouldn't. Use [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) instead.

Comment: ... if you need to use pointers at all.

Comment: i may have misunderstood, the basic summary of this is when one of my sprites is deleted it doesnt call its destructor

Comment: i believe i'm the main cause of the problem, because i'm creating multiples using the new keyword, would this prevent the destructor from being called?

Comment: @evilsponge: I bet you're leaking sprites.

Comment: how would i find out if i am, and resolve this issue ? thanks :)

Comment: @evilsponge For every call on `new`, you have to call a corresponding `delete`, there's nothing done automatically for you.

Comment: yeah each single one has a delete called on it, however none called the destructor

Comment: if you call `auto obj = new X[<number>]` then you must use `delete [] obj` to destroy them. Note the `[]` in the delete.

Comment: Post the code, please.

Answer (score 1):

the destructor of the class is called automatically when delete statement is executed. however the responsibility to delete the class variables is on the you, i mean you should delete them inside destructor explicitly. check below link...

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~siff/CS367/Notes/dynamic-memory.html